# React-Router V4, Using HashRouter. Text before hash sign still matches the route

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

```
<Switch location={location}>
 <Route path="/home" component={HomepageView} />
 <Route path="/office-solution" component={OfficeSolutionPageView} />
 <Route path="/case-studies" component={CaseStudiesPageView} />
 <Route path="/aboutUs" component={AboutUsPageView} />
 <Redirect exact={true} from="/" to="/home" />
 <Route component={NoMatch} />
</Switch>
```

So when I add text before the hash sign like this. It still matches the route. Is there any way to make it display the NoMatch component ?
http://localhost:3000/asdasd#/home

Here is an example: Just type any text before #, it still redirect to /home
https://codesandbox.io/embed/6xpk39lwjn

Comment: Can you not add `exact` to your `Route`s?

Comment: If add add exact to every routes, it still doesn't work. Beside, I have child routes in some route. My workaround is to add exact only to Redirect, So only localhost:3000/ will redirect to localhost:3000/#/home. But if I add text before the hashsign, it still matches all the routes. That is my current situation